# view shared folders for only users who shared with

Tags: windows-7, networking, network-shares

I shared a lot of folders in my PC , every folder with only one person, 
when everyone enter to my computer on network, will see all folders that I shared. and this will be confusing. becaus person will see many folders not shared with him. can I view every shared folder for only user/users who I shared with?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to achieve is called Access Based Enumeration (ABE) and is where a user can only see what they have access to.

As far as I am aware this is only available on the Server versions of Windows such as Windows Server 2003, 2008 and 2012.